# Half-installed python packages and circular dependency

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, dpkg

Something went wrong while updating to ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10:

```
root@ely:/sys/bus/usb/devices# dpkg -l | grep ^i[HUFW]
iU  libpython2.7                           2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4                        Shared Python runtime library (version 2.7)
iU  python                                 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2                        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default version)
iU  python-all                             2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2                        package depending on all supported Python runtime versions
iU  python-all-dev                         2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2                        package depending on all supported Python development packages
iU  python-dev                             2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2                        header files and a static library for Python (default)
iU  python-minimal                         2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2                        minimal subset of the Python language (default version)
iU  python2.7                              2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4                        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
iU  python2.7-dev                          2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4                        Header files and a static library for Python (v2.7)
iF  python2.7-minimal                      2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4                        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
```

When I try to configure the packages python2.7-minimal and python-minimal, I get what looks like a circular dependency:

```
root@ely:~# sudo dpkg --configure python2.7-minimal
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python2.7-minimal:
 python2.7-minimal depends on python-minimal (>= 2.6.6-3+squeeze1); however:
  Package python-minimal is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python2.7-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal


root@ely:~# sudo dpkg --configure python-minimal
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-minimal:
 python-minimal depends on python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.3); however:
  Package python2.7-minimal is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal
```

How do I resolve those python2.7-minimal <-> python.minimal dependencies? Secondly, how do I unpack or configure the iU and iF -marked packages? I can't reconfigure nor install anything in this instance. Thanks.

Update:
I purged all packages above, except python-minimal, which is essential, and can't be purged. Upon reinstall of any of the packages, I get:

```
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 243, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 520, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 419, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 298, in _init_posix
    raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/local/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h     (No such file or directory)
    dpkg: error processing python2.7-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-minimal:
 python-minimal depends on python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.3); however:
  Package python2.7-minimal is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal
 python-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now I am back to the state:

```
root@ely:~# dpkg -l | grep ^i[HUFW]
iU  python-minimal                         2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2                        minimal     subset of the Python language (default version)
iF  python2.7-minimal                      2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4                        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
```

So I think the culprit is the unpacked python-minimal library. How do I unpack it or resolve this issue?

Comment: Can't you just purge them all, then re-install all of them?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae - see edit above.

Comment: Try sudo apt-get --reinstall install python2.7-minimal

Comment: No, it complains about an unmet dependency python-dev depends on python2.7-dev which is not going to be installed. Can't install neither python-dev python2.7-dev - I get the "no apport report written..." error above. I think the problem is that python-minimal is in unconfigured state, I can't configure it. apt and dpkg themselves may depend on it?

Comment: Can anyone help - python.minimal appears to be unconfigured. It is an essential package, and the distro is broken while in this state.

Comment: If all else fails, you can use --force

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar problem.

and I also found when I run python:

```
# python
ImportError: No module named site
```

but if use the default environment variable is work

```
# python -E
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

so I set the $PYTHONPATH and $PYTHONHOME both to /usr/lib/python2.7

```
# export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7
# export PYTHONHOME=/usr/lib/python2.7
```

then install python again

```
# aptitude install python2.7
```

I guess the apt-get/aptitude depand on python, but it(python) was broken.

Hope this help!